# Bordered element position break in some resolutions

Tags: html, css

I made a curved tab list and everything looks good, but the problem is in some resolutions it break position about one pixel, I really want know why this happen technically? and how can I avoid this?

[image]

```css
#tabs ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
  top: 5px;
  margin: 0 -5px 0 0;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.active {
  border: 1px solid #0061ff !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  line-height: 50px !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
  top: 0px !important;
}

#tabcontent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#tab {
  border: 1px solid #0061ff;
  margin-top: 75px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#tabs {
  margin-top: -68px;
}

.invRadTab1 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: -33px;
  z-index: 9999999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.invRadTab2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  right: -33px;
  z-index: 9999999;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.invRadTab1 span {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #0061ff;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.invRadTab2 span {
  width: 60px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #0061ff;
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 10px;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  position: absolute;
}
li.active::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Tab 2</a></li>
      <li class="active"><a>Tab 1</a><span class="invRadTab1"><span></span></span><span class="invRadTab2"><span></span></span>
      </li>
      <li><a>Tab 3</a></li>
      <li><a>Tab 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="tabcontent">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to see this problem, you should run this snippet in full page and zoom in or zoom out (for me on 125% and 90%), my screen is 1920 and another machine is 1366, I don't see any problem in 1920 resolution, but see this break in 1366 resolution also in another screens. how can I fix this issue?

Comment: I have reviewed the full page code in Firefox 64 on my MacBook Pro 15 inch retina at 90% and 120%, but the issue is not occurring. Which browser have you been testing the code? One quick suggestion would be to add `margin-bottom:-1px;` to the active tab state, either globally or using a media query that targets that specific screen size and break point.

Comment: This effect is caused by different hdpi densities on different machines. Try to avoid using negative margins to minimize this effect.

Comment: @MikeHermary I using chrome Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)
/ Ubuntu 18

Comment: @tourtravel I have tested in Chrome 71 for Mac and the only issue is the negative right margin on the active state pulls the border one or two pixels too far, causing overlap of tab three's border. You might want to try Browserstack to see if other browsers are experiencing the same issue, and even if Chrome on Ubuntu on another machine is experiencing the same problem.